# for loop double integers as a result

Tags: python

Trying to wrap my head around this and can't fix the issue.
Basically i have a api_list that looks like:

```
[('A332', 'ZZ334', '14000', '369', '249', '52.7744', '-1.5487', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', '80.7')]
```

database_list that looks like:

```
[(204, 'A332', 'ZZ334', 15200, '390', 259, '53.1756', '0.5847', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', 28.32), (202, 'A332', 'ZZ334', 16300, '394', 259, '53.1967', '0.7807', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', 28.32)]
```

Where first element is an ID from database.

and nested for loops to check if there is no match.

```
list_to_insert = []
for x in api_list:
    for y in database_list:
        if database_list[0] == None:
            list_to_insert.append(x)
        else:
            if x[1] not in y[2]:
                list_to_insert.append(x)
```

This basically checks if from api_list value 'ZZ334' is not in database list index 2 then append x to list.

Problem is that it keep appending value it multiple times.

Any ideas?

I've tried to do without nested loops but then getting Error as i have to check if database[0] is not None..

Comment: `list_to_insert` is an empty list? What is that?

Comment: Sorry, yes that’s an empty list.

Comment: Can you please make an example of your expected output?

Comment: I ran your code but I got `[]` which is different from what you mentioned *"...it keep appending value it multiple times"*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you're asking. I've added a few elements to `database_list` with values at index 2 that don't match the value at index 1 in `api_list`, to test the logic.

```
        api_list = [('A332', 'ZZ334', '14000', '369', '249', '52.7744', '-1.5487', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', '80.7')]
        database_list = [
            (204, 'A332', 'ZZ334', 15200, '390', 259, '53.1756', '0.5847', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', 28.32), 
            (202, 'A332', 'ZZ334', 16300, '394', 259, '53.1967', '0.7807', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', 28.32),
            (202, 'A332', 'AB123', 16300, '394', 259, '53.1967', '0.7807', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', 28.32),
            (202, 'A332', 'CD456', 16300, '394', 259, '53.1967', '0.7807', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', 28.32),
            (202, 'A332', 'ZZ999', 16300, '394', 259, '53.1967', '0.7807', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', 28.32)
        ]
        list_to_insert = []
        for x in api_list:
            for y in database_list:
                if y[0] == None or x[1] != y[2]:
                    list_to_insert.append(x)
                    break
        print("list_to_insert elements:")
        [print(row) for row in list_to_insert]
```

Sample output:

```
list_to_insert elements:
('A332', 'ZZ334', '14000', '369', '249', '52.7744', '-1.5487', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', '80.7')
```

**UPDATE:**
If the goal is to build a list of all the rows in `api_list` for which the "key" (namely, the string at index 1 in `api_list`, for example 'ZZ334') is not found in any row within `database_list`, then the following code should work:

```
        api_list = [
            ('A332', 'ZZ334', '14000', '369', '249', '52.7744', '-1.5487', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', '80.7'),
            ('A332', 'ZZ000', '14000', '369', '249', '52.7744', '-1.5487', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', '80.7'),
            ('A332', 'ZZ001', '14000', '369', '249', '52.7744', '-1.5487', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', '80.7')
        ]
        database_list = [
            (204, 'A332', 'ZZ334', 15200, '390', 259, '53.1756', '0.5847', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', 28.32), 
            (202, 'A332', 'ZZ334', 16300, '394', 259, '53.1967', '0.7807', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', 28.32),
            (202, 'A332', 'AB123', 16300, '394', 259, '53.1967', '0.7807', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', 28.32),
            (202, 'A332', 'CD456', 16300, '394', 259, '53.1967', '0.7807', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', 28.32),
            (202, 'A332', 'ZZ999', 16300, '394', 259, '53.1967', '0.7807', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', 28.32)
        ]
        list_to_insert = []
        database_keys = {row[2] for row in database_list}
        for x in api_list:
            if x[1] not in database_keys:
                list_to_insert.append(x)
        print("list_to_insert elements:")
        [print(row) for row in list_to_insert]
```

Sample output:

```
list_to_insert elements:
('A332', 'ZZ000', '14000', '369', '249', '52.7744', '-1.5487', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', '80.7')
('A332', 'ZZ001', '14000', '369', '249', '52.7744', '-1.5487', 'BZZ', 'BZZ', '80.7')
```

Comment: This still gives me multiple same tuples.

I would like to have no multiple data in there. Based if ZZ334 already exists then not append it to the list.

Comment: @Stag Then What if you change the last line of this code to `[print(set(row)) for row in list_to_insert]`?

Comment: @Stag Just to confirm, are you saying that you are trying to build a list of all the rows in `api_list` for which the "key" (namely, the string at index 1 in `api_list`, for example 'ZZ334') is not found in any row within `database_list`? If so, please see the "UPDATE" section of my answer

Comment: @constantstranger, Thank you. last update worked well. Only getting one error if the database_list is empty:
__TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable__

From line: 


__database_keys_update = {row[2] for row in database_list}__


But i will figure it out how to obey the error.

Comment: I've fixed the issue just by adding if statement:
if database_list[0] == None:
    database_list = []

Comment: @Stag Nice catch on handling the empty `database_list`. Glad to hear you got this working